# How to calculate for value that is dependent on the month

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.4

I use PostgreSQL and hoping someone could help me with this. Below is a table in excel that im trying to replicate in postgres. The value of rent2 1469(March) always depend on the  value of rent1 1469(March) and this applies whenever there is a new month like april rent1=april rent2 etc. The value of Feb Rent2 will now be calculated from the value for March, 1469/(1+ 1.1)= 1453. How do i  set the value of rent2 to be exactly the same as rent1 this is the current month without affecting the previous months? And how do i compute the value of rent2 on  previous months after getting the result of rent2 for current month?

```
Month      Rent1     Rent2  Percent
-----      ----      ----
Jan2020    1447      1443   0.2%
Feb2020    1457      1453   0.7%
Mar2020    1469      1469   1.1%
```

Comment: Is rent2 only a function of rent1 in the same row?

Comment: No this will be separate function, the value for rent2 for the current month will just act as a placeholder for the computation on the previous months.

Comment: I sugest you don't couple rows like this. Keep your business logic out of your database structure.